# Netbeans blocked by chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, netbeans

I've downloaded Netbeans 7.4(https://netbeans.org/downloads/7.4/) When the download finished, chrome deleted it and says: `netbean-7.4.exe is malicious, and Chrome has blocked it.`

Is this a false alert? I'm using Netbeans for years and never get this issue.

**EDIT**
I calculated md5 hash of netbeans using [Md5checker](http://getmd5checker.com/)
MD5: 7cbf1e71ff20f1166f8ab6e81be7020e
It's OK.. but why does chrome detect it as malicious ? :/

Comment: It happens to me too

Comment: You can just go to your download tab find the installer and click recover and then you can install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome will always block files that is suspicious
For example: 

A chinese song player named Kuwo I've just downloaded recently, blocked.
LOIC, blocked
A random exe from my own server, blocked.
Just open up downloads and press the recover button with Hurt me plenty.
Seems that problem is solved but no answer was posted.
Should have helped others when there is an answer posted.